# OpenShift - how to create a new image stream?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am building an OpenShift s2i image. And to help streamline development I would like to create an image stream based on this s2i image, so that I can quickly test if changes to the s2i - and if changes in the source code base - works.

I cannot find any `oc` command to create a new image stream.

I tried to create an image stream using the below yml.

```
kind: "BuildConfig"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "s2i-cpp" 
  annotations:
    openshift.io/build-config.name: s2i-cpp
  labels:
    build: s2i-cpp
    buildconfig: s2i-cpp
    openshift.io/build-config.name: s2i-cpp
    openshift.io/build.start-policy: Serial
spec:
  source:
    contextDir: "dockerfiles/builder"
    git:
      ref: master
      uri: 'https://gitlab.com/myrepo/s2i-cpp-wine.git'
    sourceSecret:
      name: gitlab-priceinsight
    type: Git
  strategy:
   type: Docker
   dockerStrategy:
    dockerfilePath: dockerfiles/builder/
  output: 
    to:
      kind: "ImageStreamTag"
      name: "s2i-cpp:latest"
```

While I am able to create this using `oc create -f imagestream.yml`, when I try to run this, it immediately errors with `Invalid output reference`. My expectation was that it would create a new image.

Comment: Where are you building the S2I image in the first place? If building the S2I image in OpenShift itself as a ``docker`` build strategy, an image stream would be created for you. If you have pushed your image up to Docker Hub, you can use ``oc import-image``. You can also push direct into the internal image registry of OpenShift if that is accessible and you login first.

Comment: Thanks Graham. Yes I *was* able to push to the internal registry but something broke. And yes, I am building the s2i in OS. And just realized that I therefore already have an image stream. Thanks

Comment: so what was the issue at the end? and what's wrong with the @Rameez answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Move to project namescape or use -n

```
oc project <your namespace>
```

#### Create a imagestream using cli

```
oc create imagestream <image-name>
```

Image streamname should be same as in yaml file

```
output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'image-name:latest'
```

#### Create build using yaml file

```
oc create -f <build>.yaml
```